# Can secondary alkyl halides be used in the Corey–House synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I've been told by my teacher that the Corey–House synthesis cannot proceed with secondary alkyl halides; they will prefer to undergo elimination over $\mathrm{S_N2}$ substitution. [used as the pseudo halide, not the diorganyl cuprate.]. My book, however says that secondary alkyl halides do undergo the reaction. A quick google search on Wikipedia says:

> [...]RX, R = methyl, benzylic, allylic, primary, or cyclic secondary alkyl, aryl, or alkenyl

These seemingly varied responses have really left me rather confused. **Is the applicability different for different secondary halides?** If yes, why? And if no, then which is the correct answer?

Secondly, my teacher also tells me that in R-X, using Br, Cl, or F as the halogen will not produce a satisfactory yield. Again, Wikipedia goes on to say:

> [...] X = Br, I, OTs, or OTf; X = Cl is marginal.

Again,  could anyone help me out in resolving these differences? I've never really had the opportunity to see these reactions in the lab, so I feel that someone with real experience would be able to help me out.